# Http Modules are called on every request when using mvc/routing module

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, request, httpmodule

I am developing a http module that hooks into the FormsAuthentication Module through the Authenticate event.

While debugging i noticed that the module (and all other modules registered) gets hit every single time the client requests a resource (also when it requests images, stylesheets, javascript files (etc.)).
This happens both when running on a IIS 7 server in integrated pipeline mode, and debugging through the webdev server (in non- integrated pipeline mode)

As i am developing a website with a lot images which usually wont be cached by the client browser it will hit the modules a lot of unnessecary times.

I am using MVC and its routing mechanishm (System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule).
When creating a new website the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests attribute for the IIS 7 (system.webServer) section is per default set to true in the web.config, which as the name indicates make it call all modules for every single request.

If i set the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests attribute to false, no modules will get called.

It seems that the reason for this is because of the routing module or mvc (dont know excactly why), which causes that the asp.net (aspx) handler never gets called and therefore the events and the modules never gets called (one time only like supposed).

I tested this by trying to call "mydomain.com/Default.aspx" instead of just "mydomain.com/" and correctly it calls the modules only once like it is supposed.

How do i fix this so it only calls the modules once when the page is requested and not also when all other resources are requested ?

Is there some way i can register that all requests should fire the asp.net (aspx) handler, except requests for specific filetype extensions ?
Of course that wont fix the problem if i choose to go with urls like /content/images/myimage123 for the images (without the extension). But i cant think of any other way to fix it.

Is there a better way to solve this problem ?

I have tried to set up an ignoreRoute like this routes.IgnoreRoute("content/{*pathInfo}"); where the content folder contains all the images, javascripts and stylesheets in seperat subfolders, but it doesnt seem to change anything.

I can see there a many different possibilites when setting up a handler but I cant seem to figure out how it should be possible to setup one that will make it possible to use the routing module and have urls like /blog/post123 and not call the modules when requesting images, javascripts and stylesheets (etc.).

Hope anyone out there can help me ?

Martin

Comment: Moving all images, stylesheets and javascripts to a subdomain will of course solve the problem. 
But as this is a general problem with all websites using the mvc/routing module (it seems) and the same domain for all the content i hope someone out there have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the routing module.

The solution is to move images, css, js to a subdomain, or you can probably register which filetypes/extensions the routing module should ignore.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is what I use in every MVC Application in order to avoid the overhead caused by the routing system on serving static files, javascript, css, etc:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
    routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

    /* ... */
}
```